# Checking button click event and doing something and removing them if user clicks elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

I am attaching a onclick function to the button#1 and according to this function i am changing other buttons' opacity and disabling user to click on them.
But I want to undo what has been changed onclick event, making other buttons as normal. 
My javascript and jquery code as below;

```
btnLink.onclick = function(e) {
    var divToShow = document.getElementById('linkNewDiv');
    console.log('clicked');
    divToShow.style.display = 'inherit';
    $(btnVideo).prop('disabled',true);
    $(btnVideo).addClass('opacityReducing');
    $(btnPicture).addClass('opacityReducing');
    $(btnPublish).addClass('opacityReducing');
    $(btnPicture).prop('disabled',true);
    $(btnPublish).prop('disabled',true);
    $(btnCheck).addClass('opacityReducing');
```

}

I couldnt manage to figure it. I found a one way if user clicks outside of the elements I am changing elements style and disable property by writing all these codes again. Any better solutions ? Thanks :)

Comment: You need toggle between classes and prop disabled? Is not clear

Comment: I want to change the elements to the their old states defined in html and css  when user clickes outside of an button parents. I am showing input area and an icon when user clicks on it and disabling other buttons to submit without entering values to the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `stopPropagation()`. I made some changes to your code to make it more readable, check this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    $('#linkNewDiv').css("display", "inherit");
    $(btnVideo, btnPicture, btnPublish).removeClass('opacityReducing').prop('disabled', false);
    $(btnCheck).removeClass('opacityReducing');
});
$('#bnLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('clicked');
    $('#linkNewDiv').css("display", "inherit");
    $(btnVideo, btnPicture, btnPublish).addClass('opacityReducing').prop('disabled', true);
    $(btnCheck).addClass('opacityReducing');
});
```